# Show missing values with dotted lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nan, missing-data

I created a very simple chart using multiline d3.
In my dataset (csv file) there are missing values, so what I what is that lines are dotted at missing values (NaN).

My dataset is:

```
,time,group,value
1,2000,Apple,0
2,2001,Apple,0
3,2002,Apple,0
4,2003,Apple,0
5,2004,Apple,NA
6,2005,Apple,NA
7,2006,Apple,0
8,2007,Apple,0
9,2000,Banana,1
10,2001,Banana,5
11,2002,Banana,2
12,2003,Banana,3
13,2004,Banana,NA
14,2005,Banana,NA
15,2006,Banana,7
16,2007,Banana,6
17,2000,Clementine,4
18,2001,Clementine,4
19,2002,Clementine,5
20,2003,Clementine,5
21,2004,Clementine,NA
22,2005,Clementine,NA
23,2006,Clementine,2
24,2007,Clementine,1
```

Here is all the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/jQ5jnzrsmqThufNkDnT8?p=preview

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elrWC.png) is the what I have and what I want.

I think I have to modify this piece of code bit I'm not sure:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.value); }) 
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

In addition, the "Apple" group has all values to 0. Why there aren't a line? Should I see a line that overlaps the x axis..

Comment: For it to work on plnkr you need to load the d3 script with https instead of http.

Comment: Thanks, now the example code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a second pass of the code that generates the path, only this time the data is built in the following way

- find the index `i` of the next occurrence of `NA`, make `left = data[i - 1]`
- find the index `j` of the first occurrence of a value not equal to `NA`, make `right = data[j]`
- render a dashed path with those two datums i.e. render `[left, right]`, and reiterate the array from `j` with the above two steps

For your second problem note that you're rendering the axis on top of the path, instead of doing that render the axis first and then the data

### [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lu0yCh8Imfpw9joxyjnv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks so much. Why the interactivity doesn't work? Why the part of the dotted line doesn't disappears when I click on the legend?
The `id` is set, so it's strange..

Comment: It's because now there are two paths with the same id, I've changed that to use classes instead, check out the updated plunkr demo :)